# moxy jaxb: mapping member attribute

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, moxy

I'm trying to map the following class with xml binding file (jaxb-moxy):

```
public class A{
   private String name;
   private B b;
   .....
}


public class B{
   private String surname;
}
```

In the binding file I have:

```
....
<java-type name="A" xml-accessor-type="NONE">
      <java-attributes>
           <xml-element java-attribute="b$surname" name="surname"/>
           <xml-element java-attribute="name" name="name"/>
      </java-attributes>
</java-type>
....
```

Unfortunately, the xml generated has always surname field empty (and I log this error message: Ignoring attribute [b$surname] on class [A] as no Property was generated for it).

Could you help me to undestand how to map member attributes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get the following XML document:

```
<a>
    <surname>Doe</surname>
    <name>Jane</name>
</a>
```

For the classes you have posted in your question, then you could use the following mapping document.  In this document you map the `b` field to the `surname` element, and then map the single field on the `B` class with `@XmlValue`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="forum22788599"
    xml-accessor-type="FIELD">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="A">
            <xml-root-element/>
            <xml-type prop-order="b name"/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="b" name="surname"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="name"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
        <java-type name="B">
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-value java-attribute="surname"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

Comment: Your [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22790094/mapping-xml-to-java-object-that-doesnt-match-xml-structure/22864292#22864292) using `xml-path` is very helpful for similar, but more complex, mapping problems when the Java objects don't align with the XML structure. Thanks!